# Creating a layout with image extending the list item - Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create the following layout in android.[image]

I am unable to achieve the layout as shown in the image.Please ignore the image on the extreme left.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_groups_list_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:background="@drawable/normal_white_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groups_list_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Group name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groups_list_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Group Description may come for two lines" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/groups_list_image"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Comment: What do you wish to have? The image on the extreme right should be in the yellow border area?

Comment: @Kailas Im sorry that I havent explained it enough. This is a list row item.The background of list view is a gradient color..

Comment: Ok, the extreme right, do you wish to have it as an image? or a text block? So that makes your listview items contents in the order as {{image view}, {2 text views, one below the other}, {Text View}}. Just correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may helpful to you,

```
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="2dp" >

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image"
 android:layout_width="120dp"
 android:layout_height="120dp"
 android:contentDescription="@string/news" />

 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/text1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:text="@string/text1"
 android:textSize="25dp"
 android:textStyle="bold" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/text2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

 android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
 android:padding="2dp"
 android:paddingTop="20dp"

 android:text="@string/text2"
 android:textColor="#7F7F7F"
 android:textSize="10sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/textImage"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

 android:src="@drawable/image_source" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_groups_list_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groups_list_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Group name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groups_list_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Group Description may come for two lines" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/groups_list_image"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFF00"
android:padding="2dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_groups_list_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```